# Typescript function parameter as function or type

Tags: typescript

I am working with a Typescript library authored by someone else.  In one of the functions, it takes a parameter that can be a function or a value like:

```
function returnDefault<T>(defaultVal: T | () => T): T {
    if(typeof defaultVal === 'function') {
        return defaultVal();
    }
    return defaultVal;
}
```

When attempting to use this function, I am getting a Typescript error "This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type '(() => T) | (T & Function)' are callable.  Type 'T & Function' has no call signatures."  This error appears on the third line (return defaultVal();).  What am I doing wrong here or how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few things you might need to change here.

- When defining a callback as a type, you need to *enclose* it in parenthesis.
- You might have to cast your variable as a function when calling it, and as a `T` when returning it.
- You might have to use the `call` method rather than parenthesis directly.

Here is *working*, untested example.

```
function returnDefault<T>(defaultVal: T | (() => T)): T {
    if(typeof defaultVal === "function") {
        return (defaultVal as Function).call({});
    }
    return defaultVal as T;
}
```

The syntax seams to be valid [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKZRMsARVwCGIANlADwAqAfABQAmehJAavkQFyLmIA+i11ASkQBeSpwECOXAN4AoRAsQxg1KAE8ADqjjBE9AsSgsiI4cMQAiUJFgILQuYqcp0mJHQaHjifAGdEAGLg0PBgAgB0EKxE1NIAvgIA3PKKcSkKaBhYep7MrD7+5MlxQA).